# npm install error - cb() never called

Tags: npm

I try to install node_module in my angular project what I downloaded, but I get this error:

> npm ERR! registry error parsing json

Then i reinstall npm using `npm intall npm -g` and after when i try use `npm install` I get this error:

```
(node:11252) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat
'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_cacache\tmp\git-clone-ec5da46c\angular\cdk.es5.js'
```

debug.log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install' ]
2 info using npm@5.4.2
3 info using node@v6.10.2
4 verbose npm-session ff5ce249dfe37f0e
5 silly install runPreinstallTopLevelLifecycles
6 silly preinstall spa@0.0.0
7 info lifecycle spa@0.0.0~preinstall: spa@0.0.0
8 silly install loadCurrentTree
9 silly install readLocalPackageData
10 silly install loadIdealTree
11 silly install cloneCurrentTreeToIdealTree
12 silly install loadShrinkwrap
13 info lifecycle @angular/cdk@2.0.0-beta.10-a7ce31e~prepack: @angular/cdk@2.0.0-beta.10-a7ce31e
14 error cb() never called!
15 error This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
16 error <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
```

I already tried `npm cache clean --force` but i get same error.

```
node -v v6.10.2
npm -v 5.4.2
```

Comment: i had fixed same issue.  see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52467848/npm-err-cb-never-called-error-when-trying-to-run-npm-install-command/58089750#58089750

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue. I resolved it

by excluding package-lock.json file

```
npm i --no-package-lock
```

OR by manually deleting package-lock.json

Comment: i had fixed same issue.  see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52467848/npm-err-cb-never-called-error-when-trying-to-run-npm-install-command/58089750#58089750

Answer (score 2):

Run `npm cache clean --force` and perform an install.

Comment: I found my solution in this, and with the more complete instructions of this page: https://www.alex-arriaga.com/issue-when-running-npm-install-npm-err-cb-never-called-solved/

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I resolved it by remove nodejs@10 and install nodejs@8

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 10 running `npm install` gave me this error.

I solved this issue by doing so from within `Administrator: Command Prompt`.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have a `package.json` file within the root of your angular project which should look something similar to this.

https://github.com/heroku/node-js-sample/blob/master/package.json

If the package.json file exists, you run `npm install` to get the packages saved to it and that will generate a `node_modules` directory for you.

However, if the file does not exist, it means you have to initialize npm into the project by running `npm i -y` which should automatically create a package.json file for you and as well allow you to install node modules.

**NB:** You have npm installed on your machine already so running `npm install npm -g` is not ideal.

Comment: `package.json` exist, and this project worked a few weeks ago. But now I clone git and get this error.

Comment: Make sure it's in the root directory of the project where you're running `npm install`

Comment: I running in root directory. Now I tryed install this project in other computer and `node_modules` installed whithout problem, so I think problemm in `npm`. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Additionally, I added a node module to packages.json manually and removing it fixed the issue

Comment: Alright request for edit and upvote the answer. Thanks? @DeanMeehan

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when my package.json referred to a package using file:../(local path) and the directory didn't exist. Pointing it to the correct path resolved the error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case... none of the above worked. I then deleted my package-lock.json. When I ran an npm install I got an error that a certain package could not be found in the repository. When I removed that from package.json my npm install worked!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. In my case it was caused by a syntax error within the `.npmrc` file, which was manually edited

Answer (score 0):

Method 1:
`npm cache clean --force` then install your package

Method 2:
Disable your antivirus software and try to install your package

Method 3:
It is your internet connection, if you are using Wifi or an Ethernet connection use your cellular network or a different network and try to install your package