# npm ERR! cb() never called! error when trying to run npm install command

Tags: node.js, npm

I have this react-native project I worked on my other pc, and I want now to keep working on this exact project folder in my other linux machine.

So now I have the project folder, which doesn't contain node_modules directory, but it does contain "package.json". As I understood it, doing NPM install inside the directory, should install and create the node_modules directory with all the needed dependencies.
However, the operation is failed after a while with the error "npm ERR! cb() never called!"

I've already tried to clean npm cache (with -f flag) but it doesn't worked for me.
I'm running on Ubuntu 18.04 based os with Node.js v8.10.0 and npm v3.5.2.

Comment: Can you share the dependencies from your package.json?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In my case, I had an own custom node_module which is in my package.json like that:

```
// ...
"dependencies": {
    // ...
    "my-module": "file:../../my-module",
},
// ...
```

This package is only available in a specific environment (dynamically added to package.json via `npm install ../../my-module`), which is by intend,
but I forgot about it and when I ran `npm install` in another environment (where my module was **not** available)
the mysteriuos `cb() never called` error occured.

After putting the option `--no-package-lock` behind the `npm install` the error got more clear, telling me that it has something to do with `my-module`.

see also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52474959/3063191

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 4):

I my case i was able to fix it by deleting

1. `node_modules`
2. `package-lock.json`

and then running `npm install`

Answer (score 3):

I had similar issue for git project. The Project configuration had created bad `.npmrc` file, which was preventing package installation. I resolved it by deleting the `.npmrc` file, then performing hte following steps:

1. Delete the `node_modules` folder from project, if it exists
2. Delete temp files from machine
3. Run `npm cache clean --force`
4. Run `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

Manually delete the package-lock.json file and then run "npm install". It should re-generate the package-lock.json.

Answer (score 0):

let me save your time , Just install latest Nodejs. I was trying all day. Finally this solved