# npm crashes with "ERR! cb() never called"

Tags: node.js, npm, vue-cli

I was trying to install vue-cli using

> npm install -g @vue/cli

I get the following error

```
Unhandled rejection Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/moeketsi/.npm/_cacache/tmp'

npm ERR! cb() never called!

npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://npm.community>

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!  /home/moeketsi/.npm/_logs/2019-08-02T07_16_39_683Z-debug.log
```

The log file is [available here](https://gist.github.com/miraselimo/477220bdbffc2150a76a514585c1cc2a).

When i try running the command with `sudo` I get

```
sudo: npm: command not found
```

I'm using node v10.16.1 and npm vesrsion is 6.9.0 . I installed  node.js from their [website](https://nodejs.org/en/). I tried the following suggestions from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52467848/npm-err-cb-never-called-error-when-trying-to-run-npm-install-command) and from maybe a  [slightly different case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393821/npm-err-cb-never-called), none of the suggestions helped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the Issue of permission . Go to the root and try to install.

Try from root user :

```
sudo -i

npm install -g @vue/cli
```

If u want to maintain current directory.

```
sudo -s

npm install -g @vue/cli
```

Answer (score 5):

According to the [documentation](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html) you might have issues if you have previous versions installed. You can check all the packages installed with `npm list -g`.

To uninstall previous versions of vue-cli use `npm uninstall vue-cli -g`

If this is not the case you can try running `npm cache clear --force` and try to install it again.