# (npm error) when creating Vue-CLI project

Tags: vue.js, npm, vue-cli

Basically I am trying to create a new Vue-CLI project. However, there is a npm error alert at the very end of the creation:

```
Vue CLI v4.5.11
✨  Creating project in C:\Eric\apps\vueproj\modal-project.
  Initializing git repository...
⚙️  Installing CLI plugins. This might take a while...

npm ERR! cb() never called!

npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://npm.community>

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Eric\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-02-05T07_09_25_978Z-debug.log
```

How can I solve it? Please help me on this...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm crashes with "ERR! cb() never called"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57321811/npm-crashes-with-err-cb-never-called)

Comment: Not at all, even I run the command "vue create something" as an administrator (FYI, I am using Windows), the problem still exists.